# How to install Xfig

Tags: vector, xfig

I want to install Xfig.
I downloaded Xfig from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcj/), but I can't install it. 
I have searched a manual on the internet. But I haven't found useful manual.
Could any one help me? I am using Windows 10.
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to TeX ...

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. You can not install **Xfig** but **Winfig** for OS W10. http://winfig.com/

Comment: With which system are you working ? It's adapted for linux. All is explained here : http://mcj.sourceforge.net/frm_installation.html

Comment: ...really? I am a die-hard xfig user, but just for lazyness... ;-)

Comment: @Sebastiano is there any program that you suggest like winfig?